# get contact thumbnail Uri from contact list by using recipient_id

Tags: android, contacts

I am new to android, I am trying to get contact thumbnail by using `recipient_id`, I am getting `recipient_id` from `content://mms-sms/conversations` and new I want to get thumbnail by using this id, but my code is not working, please help.
This is my function:

```
public static Uri getPhotoUriFromID(Context context, String id) {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                + "="
                                + id
                                + " AND "
                                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                + "='"
                                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                + "'", null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return null; // no photo
            }
        } else {
            return null; // error in cursor process
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id));
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Comment: Is there a build error or run time error ? any log ?

Comment: no error, just return null

Comment: can you log the `if` statements? is it red at `//no photos` or `// error in cursor process`

Comment: it shows log in if() statement // no photos, but in contact list i have set the photos of contact

Comment: can we use recipient_id as contact id?